# RavendB: Select and GroupBy - cannot use Map/Reduce Index

Tags: ravendb

I've got following data structure.

```
public class Usage
{
  public string Id { get; set;}
  public string CatalogNumber { get; set;}
  public string ProductDescription { get; set;}
  public string ProductType { get; set;}
  public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set;}
  public int AmountSold { get; set;}
}
```

I would like to have the result grouped by {CatalogNumber}, {ProductDescription}, {ProductType} within a specific {DeliveryDate}

ie. I'd like to query the total amount sold for a specific product within 2013-01-01 to 2013-04-04.

Expected result:

```
{
  {
    CatalogNumer: 12345
    ProductDescription: Product1
    ProductType: TV
    TotalAmountSold: 125
  }
{
    CatalogNumer: 8797
    ProductDescription: Product2
    ProductType: Fridge
    TotalAmountSold: 13
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot use a Map/Reduce index because there's no way to pass parameters to the index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass parameters to the index. First create a map/reduce index grouped by `DeliveryDate`. Then you query that index with the desired date range.

Comment: I don't want to group the result by deliverydate - only filter it by this field

Comment: But you want to aggregate the data based on the date, don't you?

Comment: Yes and no - I want to aggregate the data by {CatalogNumber}, {ProductDescription}, {ProductType} within a specific Date-Range. 

I can't aggregate by date - what should I do if the Date contains also time information? That's why aggreagation by DeliveryDate is no option.